# Combine contents of selected text files with into 1 text file with Mac Automator and Services

Tags: service, automator

I am trying to combine the contents of selected text files in Finder into 1 text file, using the Services context menu and control-clicking on .txt files.

I have started a new Service Workflow in Automator, added the steps I think should work (see attached workflow file) and saved the file.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7x9CADuUNaQRjhneklJQmNuT2s/view?usp=sharing

The problem is that the Services menu doesn't pop up when I have text files selected in Finder.  It pops up when I have PDF files selected in Finder, but that's no help as the output file doesn't work.

Any ideas how to correct it so that it can work with selected text files?

Thanks in advance.

Ryan

Comment: I cannot see your workflow with the link, can you list the Actions, please?

Comment: You have to download the file...

Comment: Can you see this screenshot?

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7x9CADuUNaQYV9VVXhUYjN3YmM/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Got it.  See answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the final version.  Your trial had chosen the incorrect Action to ignore:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Craig Smith,

That helped a lot.  At least I can select .txt files for processing now.

See below.

Comment: I corrected the ComboName variable by selecting "Ignore this action's input" for "Ask for Text".

Now the workflow runs and flashes at the end and no file is created, but there are no errors in the log.

Maybe you could help figure that out?  Team work this one. :)

http://i.imgur.com/LeZ4Zja.png

Comment: Done.  See repaired workflow above.  The little graphic connections between the Actions can help to know where in the chain to ignore input.  I should have thought of that originally.